# Do circularly static linked libs result in a bigger output size?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have multiple static libraries in C++. For example:

- lib a
- lib b
- lib c

*lib a* uses *lib c* and *lib c* uses *a* and *b* uses both. We have a circular dependencies between the libs. Because they are static libs is the output size bigger if they are circular, because they are included both in *b*. *a* is included in *c* and *c* in a sode the code is in *b* twice :(

Can somebody explain me how this works?

And if *a*, *b* and *c* would be linked to *d* would be the code of *c* inside *d* twice too?

Comment: If they are indeed static, nothing is actually resolved until the final link of whatever executable image (dll, exe, sys, whatever) is manufactured. In short, no, there should be no size differences, though I would think it would have been easy to test this for yourself.

Comment: Did you check that already at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is the output size bigger [when linked multiple times]?

No, the output size of your executable does not change with the order of your libs and also not with the number of times you specify the libs.

> Can somebody explain me how this works?

**When creating an executable (not a library):** The linker usually links on `*.o` file granularity, which means that either a *.o file is included in the executable or not. But each `*.o` file is included in the executable only once. This is why the size does not differ, even if you link lib a three times.

> And if a, b and c would be linked to d would be the code of c inside d
>   twice too?

Static libraries are usually not linked together. They are just repackaged together as a new `ar` archive. And, like in the executable case, each *.o file stays in the new library (the new `ar` archive) only once, so the size does not get bigger, even if you add a library twice, directly or indirectly.

**Reducing executable size:** If you are concerned about the size of your executable and you are using gcc or LLVM, there is a nice way which allows you to reduce it:

- Tell gcc to put each individual function into an individual section: `-ffunction-sections`
- Then tell the linker to garbage collet (discard) unused sections: `-Wl,--gc-sections`

It is surprising that this is not the default. Without these options always the entire `*.o` file is present in the executable if at least one thing in this `*.o` file is referenced. Unused `*.o` files are always discarded as well (unless specific options are provided), but not on function-level.

Linking dynamic libraries (shared objects, DSO, whatever you want to call them) is again a different matter on UNIX systems and more complex.

Comment: About reducing executable size, are you aware of equivalent options in MSVC? I am trying to reduce my executable (built using static libs) size on MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries don't get statically linked to each other; they get statically linked in to executables.

So, it doesn't matter what libraries refer to each other — *lib a* will never contain a copy of *lib c* (excepting the possibility of code inlining).

Your linker, when building your executable, will also pull in each dependent library only once.

However, said executable will be larger than it would be if you were *dynamically* linking these libraries, and every other executable that you make with the same libraries will have its own copy of them too. That's the layer to be thinking about here.

Comment: I would like to accept your both, ur answer is awesome too, thank you very much :)